# Model binding fails with Kendo MultiSelect

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

In the model I have `long?` field that I like to use Kendo MultiSelect for it. The main reason for this choice is `server-side filtering`. It doesn't reflect current Model's value, nor it sends any value to the server. By inspected traffic, I'm sure that it doesn't update the model's value.

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x => x.theField)
    .Name("msname")
    .MaxSelectedItems(1)
    .Placeholder("")
    .HighlightFirst(true)
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .AutoBind(true)
    .DataSource(ds =>
        ds.Read(" ", "API").ServerFiltering(true))
    .Value(new long?[] { Model.theField})
)
```

I can put a hidden field and update its value or multiselect's change, but there should be a better solution.

I should note that this multi select is in an editor template and is used by Kendo Grid in popup editor.

**UPDATE**

When using `nullable` types, you need to use `ValuePrimitive(true)`! So the end code is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x => x.theField)
    .MaxSelectedItems(1)
    .Placeholder("")
    .HighlightFirst(true)
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .AutoBind(true)
    .DataSource(ds =>
        ds.Read(" ", "API").ServerFiltering(true))
    .ValuePrimitive(true)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The main reason for this choice is `server-side filtering`

You can find on their demo site that `DropDownList` and `ComboBox` also support that feature. But if you insist to use `MultiSelect` then lets dig some of your code.

Look `Name()` method will give a name for your input element e.g (`input`, `select`). When form serialized it will use our input name as form's field property. If you are using `HtmlHelper` that ends with "For" e.g (`LabelFor`, `MultiSelectFor`) input attribute name will be named by its binded property.

```
Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x => x.theField)
```

You will have

```
<select name="theField"> ....
```

You don't have to use `Name()` method anymore, therefore MultiSelect value will be binded as `theField` property as per form serialized to server.

Now if you look to `Request.Form["theField"]` when you debug inside your controller, you will see what value being sent. It usually a content of joined string array if multiple items selected, so you need to change `theField` type to handle **array** of `string` or `int`  instead of `nullable long` type.

**EDIT**

At last you find the way to solve your problem, this solution credit to Akbari

> When using nullable types, you need to use .ValuePrimitive(true)

Comment: I can not comprehend your problem, could you make a little sample project that reproduce your current situation? maybe it will enlighten me to find the solution..

Comment: Thanks for your effort Dion, the issue is that If the model's field, `theField` is currently `null`, I'm not able to change it, neither of the controls will update its value. But if it has some value already, I'm able to change it and both controls will update it just fine. Unfortunately, I'm not able to put a sample.

Comment: 1 minute please Dion, I think I got the problem, it's probably because of type difference, The Multi Select's data aren't nullable.

Comment: Please update your answer with big, scary font that when using nullable types, you need to use `.ValuePrimitive(true)`!

Comment: Alhamdulillah, glad you find the way bro. As your command, it's done :D